# postfix HOLD Recieved non authenticated

Tags: postfix, authentication, smtp-headers, pcre

i'm wondering if is possibile to put on hold emails that not have authenticated in Recieved header .

i've tryed with a simple negate operazione with pcre

```
!/^Received:.*Authenticated*/ HOLD
```

but don't works , nothing is mentioned about negation in pattern, anyone can suggest me a way to have this ?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

As documented, header_checks work on one header a time and don't keep any memory of previous header lines. To achieve what you want, you need to use a content_filter.